# Quartz Cron Expression: Run Job Every 10 minutes starting NOW (immediately)

Tags: cron

I am using Quartz Scheduler using Spring. I want to configure the same with following schedule:

> Run Job Every 10 minutes starting NOW

I am using following expression for the same.

```
0 */10 * * * ?
```

I thought * in the minutes field would make it run the first minute, but it does not do that way. It runs the first 10th minutes from now and then every 10 minutes afterwards.
Can anybody please suggest me the reason for this behavior and the solution to my problem also?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

check the minute your at now and add them as a list to your crontrigger. if you start the trigger at minute 12 for example add

```
0 2,12,22,32,42,52 * * * ?
```

as your cron expression

Edit:

Another solution would be to define a simpletrigger that repeats every ten minutes

```
SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger("myTrigger",
                                            null,
                                            new Date(),
                                            null,
                                            SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY,
                                            10L * 60L * 1000L);
```

Comment: Thanks that would work, but thats not very smart, is not it. I am working on huge application which onstartup will require the CronJob to be started. 
I dont want to change the cron expression every time i am going to start my application. Do we have some alter solution please?

Comment: i fear that the smarter version is not configurable through spring.

Comment: you can add @PostContruct before your method, so after your bean is initialized, it runs for the first time.

Answer (score 22):

```
0 0/10 * 1/1 * ? *
```

Please see : http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
0 1-59/10 * * * ?
```

That will trigger the job at any minute and 10 minutes after that. I didn't try it but it looks right. :)

Comment: you save the day.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more up to date suggestion:

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("myTrigger", "myGroup")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInMinutes(10)
                    .repeatForever())
            .build();
```

Answer (score -5):

```
*/10 * * * *
```

Every 10 minutes starting from the moment you create the cron job, wether you prefer (user crontab, `/etc/cron.d/`, ...).

Comment: in quartz, crons can run every second.  Your solution would run every 10 seconds in quartz cron scheduling syntax.  This tripped me up when I had a job that I was testing to run every minute, so I used gnu's cron syntax (like above), and actually had it running every second of every minute.  ughhhh..... talk about concurrency testing...